# firstDay option in fullcalendar does not work properly

Tags: fullcalendar

I was surprised that firstDay option in fullcalendar does not works properly. When im setting firstDay = 1 (it means monday as first day of week), the top labels over month are getting changed but dates are not changing.

see the screen shots for better understanding.

[image]

[image]

Help me to sort out this issue please.

thanks in advance.

Comment: works fine for me. Can you add your code?

Comment: add a link to codepen or fiddle